# DB2 Connection Authorization Faliure Occured Reason: Security Mechanism not supported in Java

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, db2, spring-jdbc

I am trying to configure DB2 connection with DB2JDBC Type4 drivers. But I am getting this error.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:
>   [jcc][t4][201][11237][3.64.104] Connection authorization failure
>   occurred.  Reason: Security mechanism not supported. ERRORCODE=-4214,
>   SQLSTATE=28000

My code is

```
public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
                                         IllegalAccessException, SQLException{

   Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName ( "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" ).newInstance(); 
  DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
  Connection  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://hostname:portnumber
                                           /DBName", "username","password" );
    System.out.println( "From DAO, connection obtained " );
    return connection;  
}
```

Exception log:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:
[jcc][t4][201][11237][3.64.104] Connection authorization failure occurred. 
Reason: Security mechanism not supported. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:677)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:120)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.f(b.java:2389)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:1712)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.b(y.java:3612)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.a(y.java:477)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.a(y.java:117)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1221)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:788)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:760)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:421)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:396)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:334)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:232)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:198)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:475)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:116)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at com.test.connection.DB2ConnectionFactory.getConnection(DB2ConnectionFactory.java:19
    at com.test.connection.ConnectionTest.main(ConnectionTest.java:18)
```

I also have tried these supported mechanisms by IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ

```
-CLIENT
-SERVER
-SERVER_ENCRYPT
-DATA_ENCRYPT
-KERBEROS
-GSSPLUGIN
-KRB_SERVER_ENCRYPT
-GSS_SERVER_ENCRYPT
```

In order to avoid encryption problem we have deployed this application to linux box. SO in case need secure connection, but same error is occurring there.

I am using DB2 JDBC Driver version `v10.1fp1_jdbc_sqlj`, and I have also tried `9.5` and `9.1` and `db2jcc4.jar` file for this purpose.

I have also tried it using `type 2` drivers, but I am getting ClassNotFound error in that case `COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver`. class not found.

But nothing worked so far. Any help is appreciated. I am struggling with this problem over a week.

Answer (score 3):

It's working now. The problem was with DB2. You have to make sure that your environment variables point to the correct folders. So make sure to do the following:

- Must reboot your machine after each change or after all the change you made to your environment  variables.
- Make sure that you are using `JDBC Type 2` drivers. Do not go for `Type 4` unless asked by your DBA.

Will help you to make sure that your code will be able to interact with Windows JDBC Drivers

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jdbc.dll
```

`LIB` will help your code to read right libraries. i.e `COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver`

```
LIB=;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB
```

ClassPath:

```
ClassPath = .;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.jar;
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\sqlj.zip;
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jdbc.dll;
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\sqlj.zip;
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.jar;
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\jdk;
```

Comment: Also must install DB2 Connect, it will automatically set your Environment Variable. But Still make sure they are correctly set and point to right folders

Comment: Don't forget to accept the working answer, even if it is your own.

Answer (score 0):

Type 2 driver is used when you have the Data server client installed in you machine. If you are running DB2 server in the same client machine, you can you Type 2 server.

Try to use the data server client, in order to catalog the remote database in your local machine, and try to establish a connection via "db2 connect to DBName"
If you can establish the connection, you can do the same in Java. If you can't, you can chanqe the catalogation options, till found the right one. Once you have done that, you can connect to the remote database.

Comment: But how about if we are deploying this application on linux box? means we do not need to set any thing there, we thought that this might be the issue on local machine, so we moved this app to dev box. But still the same issue. With DB2 jdbc type 2 drivers I am getting error that "myuserid" is not authenticated for this kind of operation.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][4038][12241][3.57.82] T2LUW exception: SQL1092N  "UserID" does not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation.
 ERRORCODE=-1092, SQLSTATE=

Comment: Have you established a connection to the database outside Java? with the same user and password. Probably, there is a configuration error in the database, I mean, there is an authentication method that does not correspond to the current implementation.

Comment: yes, I have configured the connection using DB2 client Configuration assistant, I have selected a data encrypt authentication and is working. But when I select USER_PASSWORD_AND_DATA_ENCRYPTION. its throwinf me error

Comment: encryptionAlgorithm can only be set with securityMechanism ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD_SECURITY and ENCRYPTED_USER_AND_PASSWORD_SECURITY.

Comment: Ok, you cataloged the database, what about the connection? did you connect to the database?

Comment: You have to check the instance creation (Auth type), also the catalogation conf, and the security plugin in the instance if any. This is a typical conf error, but difficult to solve at distance.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time, I figured out the problem and in above post I explained what it takes.. :)

Comment: Can you give more details, in order to share your conclusions to the community?

Comment: Sure, The problem was jdbc.dll file was not in the PATH variable. So I defined following system variables 
PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2jdbc.dll, this helps you to make sure that your code will able to interact with Windows JDBC Drivers

    LIB=;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB

    LIB will help your code to read right libraries. i.e (COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)

Answer (score -1):

What authentication method is configured on the server? Is any custom authentication plugin used? You can obtain this information by running `db2 get dbm cfg` on the database server.

Comment: I just talked to DBA. they says they have not imposed any such mechanism. Also, in the existing SOAP application they are not using any separate authentication other than username and password.

Comment: In the DB2 Client I am clicking option DATA_ENCRYPT in security section and is working

Comment: But not working through Java application. DBA told me to choose ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSOWRD, but not Working!!!!