# Vanilla Java on Windows to connect with DB2 on z/OS

Tags: java, db2

I am trying to use simple java (minus any framework like Spring or containers like Tomcat etc) to connect to DB2 on mainframe. Here are the steps I took.

Added the db2 drivers to my local maven repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar  -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc  -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=db2jcc4.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc4 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Created a simple java project using maven archetype. Added the following to the pom.xml

```
    <!-- Connect to DB2 on Mainframe. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc </artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4 </artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now created a simple Junit and added the following

```
    Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")
            .newInstance();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:db2://server:port/dbname", "username",
            "password");
```

This does not work. It tells me

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2010][11246][4.13.80] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Local security service non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000
```

I tried changing the driver type as well.

```
Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver");
```

But did not work. Still same problem.

I am working off a Windows machine and I have made no configuration for connecting to DB2 at all.

However, from the same Windows machine, using IBM Datastudio, and using the same credentials, I am able to connect to the database and run queries.

The stacktrace

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2010][11246][3.62.80] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: Local security service non-retryable error. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:674)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:120)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.q(b.java:2072)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:1669)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.r(ab.java:809)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.k(ab.java:363)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:136)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.Vc(b.java:1276)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1195)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:5511)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:760)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:703)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:389)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:318)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:460)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at javahelloworld.poc.DB2ConnectTest.test(DB2ConnectTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Please help.

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705749/db2-connection-authorization-faliure-occured-reason-security-mechanism-not-supp

Comment: I did check that before posting. Our errors are different. Also, I am trying to run it with type 4 driver which should mean that I should not need to do any environment configuration on Windows, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: If anything, `db2jcc_license.jar` is insufficient to connect to DB2 on z/OS. You need the license file `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar`

Comment: My bad. db2jcc_license.jar is the db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar. It was a copy paste mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work. A few things that were wrong with my original attempt.

1. Both db2jcc_license_cisuz-1.0.jar and db2jcc4-V97FP5.jar are required in the class path. Putting them in your local maven repository and adding them in the pom.xml is fine. However, both of them have to be there. This is how my pom.xml looks now. You could add them both in the classpath by any other method.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
       <artifactId>db2jcc_license</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
       <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. This driver works fine.

   Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
       Connection connection1 = DriverManager
               .getConnection(
3. Finally, something that took embarassingly long amount of time for me to figure out. Since we are talking about connection to DB2 on z/OS it might have some additional restrictions of password (those which might not apply to your regular dev environment of windows / linux), that are easy to forget.

Take care of these things and you should be all set. Thanks.